# How to use Waitr::Browser to show dynamic site content for Nokogiri to scrape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, watir

I created a scraper that finds jobs on various career sites.
On about 80% of the sites it works but I have a hard time making it work on the rest of the pages.

I thought the reason is that some of the pages have JavaScript on their page which generates dynamic content. And therefore the scraper fails. So I tried Watir as well as Mechanize, but still it does not work.

https://www.climeworks.com/careers/ is an example URL. Can anyone  scrape it?

Here is my Watir scraper:

```
def watirscraper
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'watir'

  puts "starting newscraper"
  opts = {
      headless: true
    }

  # if (chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil))
  #   opts.merge!( options: {binary: chrome_bin})
  # end

  browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, opts

  browser.goto self.career_url
  company = self
  job_url = self.career_url

  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
  jobtitle = html_doc.css(":contains('Developer'):not(:has(:contains('Developer')))").map(&:text)
  puts jobtitle

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to wait for the page to stabilize before you can pull the content. Many client-side applications need at least a few seconds to boot up, some more.

One way to refactor this:

```
def wait_for_content(browser, selector)
  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)

  return if (html_doc.css(selector).first)

  sleep(5)

  # May want to have a limit here so it doesn't spin forever
  redo
end
```

Where you can call it like:

```
wait_for_content(browser, ":contains('Developer'):not(:has(:contains('Developer')))")

jobtitle = ...
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: I did try it with a headless browser. I used the gem Watir for that.

Comment: You may need to use something like [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org) to produce the HTML that Nokogiri can parse.

Comment: I added my watir scraper in my initial question.

Comment: You may need to wait for the client-side application to load in your browser before you can scrape it. Calling `browser.html` before it's had a chance to execute will give you very little to work with.

Comment: that sounds interesting. How do I make nokogiri/watir wait for - lets say 1 sec - in my code above?

Comment: It really depends. Some sites load in *enormous* amounts of JavaScript and CSS in order to get running, others are really lean. Even then the site may require connecting to the server to download additional data or assets. I'd test in an actual browser starting with an empty cache to see how long it takes, then adjust your delay accordingly. Look for the worst-case scenario.

Comment: You can also try parsing early, and if it comes back with nothing to grab on to, wait and try again. `loop do` is good for this, as is the `redo` statement.

Comment: okay but where to put the sleep? before  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)?

Comment: Yeah, just wait a bit before you pull `browser.html`.

Comment: I just tried it. It works! thats amazing. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi, when you use WATIR to scrap the page using WATIR you don't have to wait explicitly. please see my answer below.

Comment: You could try waiting on window.requestIdleCallback. Watir doesn't seem to do async scripts though so you would have to switch to selenium

Comment: @pguardiario Watir is using selenium internally.

Comment: @Raja yes but it doesn't expose that method (#execute_async_script)

Comment: @pguardiario But if you still wanted to use selenium method, you could use like `b.driver.find_element(name: 'q').send_keys 'raj'`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using an isolated Nokogiri statement like `Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)` inside Watir code. When you use code like this, you can't call methods on Watir elements.

All you have to do here is install the `watigiri` gem which is an addon for Watir. Once you have installed it, you can the method `text!` on an element object which automatically uses Nokogiri  internally. But this method doesn't wait for the page to be loaded completely,

If the page is being loaded while you are scraping it, you have to use `text` on the element.

Watir uses Nokogiri when you write:

```
b.element(name: "something").text!
```

Watir uses Selenium when you write:

```
b.element(name: "something").text
```

For more info see [Watigiri](http://watir.com/watigiri/).